# What happens when a scion from an older tree is grafted to a younger rootstock?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees, grafting

I recently grafted a cutting of an older mango tree to a younger root stock (1-2 years old). I am curious what's going to happen. Will the tree fruit earlier?

Answer (score 6):

**Almost all** scions are from older trees than the rootstock, except when topworking an old tree to change variety.

Then again, scions are generally the "less than 1 year old" wood from the older tree, for best success when grafting.

It will probably make no difference in time of fruiting. In some cases of precocious fruit set (within 1 or 2 years of grafting, but I'm familiar with apples, not mangos) it is advisable to remove all the fruit until the graft union is stronger.